# Is there any way to rotate a vertex so that it snaps/aligns to a non-radial edge?

Tags: snapping

I am trying to figure out if there's a good way to rotate a vertex so that it lines up with an edge that crosses the path of its rotation. It's not a radial edge, so I can't just snap to one of the vertices.

[image: Snap to edge doesn't actually do anything useful.]

Setting the Snap to edge obviously doesn't do anything useful, because it snaps to anywhere on that edge, not the point at which the rotation brings the vertex closest.

Is there any better way to do this other than zooming in real close and tediously doing it by hand?

Comment: The ruler tool  is another way to visualize and try and keep constant radius value.